# ER relation with unique key

Tags: database-design, unique-constraint, database-diagrams

I've a problem about my ER diagram. Assume that I want to draw a diagram with *student*, *member* and *team*. Here is my specs:

1. A *student* does not have to be a *member* of any *team*.
2. A *student* could be a *member* of **at most** one *team*.
3. `member` has a unique member ID.

I did my ER Diagram:

```
                                                  member-id (key attribute)
                                                            |
--------                          -                    -----------
- team -------------------- -  - mem -   ------------- - student -
--------                          -                    -----------
```

As I said before, *student* does not have to be a *member* of any *team*. ***In this case, my diagram works fine?*** I asked it because of the `member_id` is a unique key.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I see two possible problems in your model:

1. `Member` of a team can exist without a reference to `Student`.

   1.1. If you delete a `Member` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` foreign key option in `Student` it will remove your student.

   1.2. If you delete a `Student`, there might be a `Member`, that not referenced to any `Student`.
2. If you would like to place `Member` properties to `Student` table, then you will have to set them to `NULL` each time, then you need to unreference `Student` and `Member`. Also it will lead to table `Student` will loose it's independence. If you would not do that, this proplem will never happen.

---

I might suggest something like *this* instead:

[image: Diagram]

*Where:* **AI** = `AUTO_INCREMENT`, **NN** = `NOT NULL`, **UN** = `UNSIGNED`.

1. Student can not exist in two teams, because there might be only one record in table `Member` for each `Student` record.
2. Student can be a member if record in the `Member` table exists for the `Student` table record. However, he might have no record in the `Member`, but still have a record in the `Student` table. Means, that he is not member of any team.

*How to achieve that?*

1. Make a primary key of the `Member` table to be a foreign key, that referes to `Student` table's primary key. `PRIMARY KEY`s are `UNIQUE` by default and can not have duplicate values. So there wouldn't be two records in the `Member` table for one record of table `Student`.
2. Make a foreign key for the table `Member`, that referes to the `Team` table's primary key. Only member can have a team.
3. As there is only one record for each `Student` can be placed in `Member` table, each student will have to be only in one team.
4. If you delete `Member` record, `Student` associated record will no longer be a member of any team, but still be a student.

*Test script (assuming MySQL RDBMS):*

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `test`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Team` (
  `IDTeam` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `etc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDTeam`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Student` (
  `IDStudent` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDStudent`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Member` (
  `IDMember` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `TeamID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `etc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`IDMember`),

  INDEX `fk_Member_Team` (`TeamID` ASC),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_Member_Student`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IDMember`)
    REFERENCES `Student` (`IDStudent`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_Member_Team`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TeamID`)
    REFERENCES `Team` (`IDTeam`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: It can be done simpler: just add a nullable TeamId to your Students table.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov But what if `Member`s may have properties, that not related to `Student`s ?

Comment: I do not see this requirement just yet. As such, we should use the simplest working solution - we can easily refactor and add complexity later. YAGNI.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov , you may be right `;)`. Still I believe, that YAGNI more suits to application code, but not to database model. Normalization will kill application implementation too, if there is no abstraction layer (like stored routines) between actual storage structure and application sql queries. Primarily opinion-based suggestion. You may write your version as another answer, of course. Both version have rights exist. Good note though, thanks.